# Dockerfile set proxy in container bulding misp

Tags: docker, proxy

I want to build the docker image from https://github.com/harvard-itsecurity/docker-misp with the build.sh file. I pass the  --build-arg HTTP_PROXY and --build-arg HTTPS_PROXY and for most of the RUN sections it works with the $HTTP_PROXY/$HTTPS_PROXY (git, wget, apt-update,...). But for

```
RUN 
...
sudo -u www-data -H php composer.phar require kamisama/cake-resque:4.1.2 ; \
sudo -u www-data -H php composer.phar config vendor-dir Vendor ; \
sudo -u www-data -H php composer.phar install
```

the proxy env variables do not work. I was dealing with a lot of different options, but I always get the error for the php part.

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
  [Composer\Downloader\TransportException]
  The "https://packagist.org/packages.json" file could not be downloaded: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known
  failed to open stream: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known
```

It seems to load external files within the previously downloaded files and the it could not handle the provided proxy variables.

Maybe there is someone who already had the same problem and could post additional help?